# Backbone object global

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, web

I am developping an application with backbone

Is it possible to create an object global :

- when I navigate some page I push `data` in my Object global?
- can I get data from my Object any time?

thank you for your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `window.yourObject` - window is globally accessible if you are not changing/refreshing the page (using hash url's or pushState: true).

If this is not the case, you can use localstorage or cookies to make data available across different pages.

Comment: I have several page and I often refresh them.
and What about history of HTML 5? It can be used?

Comment: My goal is to store visited pages of my application

Comment: If you want to store the entire page markup go for localstorage. If you just want to have a index of visited pages use cookies.